# Best way to save user's login info on iPhone

Tags: iphone

What is the best way to save user's login info on the iPhone? Is encrypting and saving in a file a good choice?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look into the documentation for the Keychain services.
The keychain provides everything you need for storing user's credentials.